# Is there a blender add-on or feature that allows for imports and exports of .cmo files?

Tags: export, import

I need to import a model, which is in a **.cmo** file type, and for the past day I have looked everywhere on the internet and could not find a method. So I went back to my trusty blender to try, but there were no importers that allowed for a **.cmo** file.

Comment: What is a cmo file, what does it contain and where does it come from?

Comment: It's very technical, and I myself don't know, but I am trying to export the files from a game, not to steal them but edit them. They turned out to be, in a .cmo file type which had me thinking it might be developed by the same person who made the game. It may be a file type they created to prevent people like me editing their models.

Comment: CMO is the (defunct) Virtools game engine format (Dassault Systems sinked the company and the product).